# Team explorer for android studio like visual studios

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any **plugin for android studio** that would enable 2 computers running android studio to run the same project and synchronize the files whensoever its edited on one computer to both of them? If not,**can we use git** to do the same ?

Comment: you can use GIT, SVN

Comment: yes you can use git to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Git or any other from below list.

1. CVS
2. Subversion
3. Mercurial
4. GitHub